# SharePoint document library template generated document inserting <div... in multiline text field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepointdocumentlibrary, document-template

I have a document library that generates a document from an item in the list using a template document. Instead of just the text content that's in the field, I'm getting
`<div class="ExternalClassStringOfHexadecimalCharacters">actual content from field</div>`
This is incorrect on a MS Word document. The other fields in this generated document don't have this problem. There's a date, a name, another multiline text field and a couple of more single line text fields. These all come across into the Word document just fine.

The content of the fields are built in InfoPath. The data looks correct when viewed in the columns of the document library. The document is generated as part of a work flow:
[image: work flow]
[image: create list item step]

The Recipient field used to be a single line of text. I switched it to Recipient Long which has multiple lines of text (like Justification) in both the source list and the document generation list. This switch was also done in the final generation process (another library from the same source list) which works just fine. It's just the draft memo generation where the extraneous div notation appears.

I was not expecting the div html text to be in the generated Word document. The original document list was created in SharePoint 2013. We recently upgraded to SharePoint 2019. I tried creating another draft generated document library, but I can't get the template to be a Word document. SharePoint insists on keeping it a Word template document.